# Expression Builder for conditional formating with strings

Tags: ms-access

I am using Access report and using conditional highlighting. 
I click on the expression Builder, and cant figure out how to check if the field is equal to "string1" or "string2" or "string3"

I tried:  "AOI2" or "AOI3"
 but then it don't Highlight anything.

EDIT
Tried: `[linenum]="AOI2" Or [linenum]="SMD1" Or [linenum]="SMD2" Or [linenum]="AOI21" Or [linenum]="MOD15" Or [linenum]="MOD17" Or [linenum]="AOI3" Or [linenum]="AOI20" Or [linenum]="MOD14"`

but does not work. looks like this. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Conditional Formatting rule, have to use
`Expression Is: [Fieldname]="AO12" Or [Fieldname]="AO13"`

Comment: never mind found I had to select express instead of field value.